# Launch an android app from Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have been trying to open an Android app from an Ionic app. for that I have downloaded com.lampa.startapp plugin. I am calling an android app on a button click. But I am getting an error in my console saying that Cannot read property 'start' of undefined. This is my controller code:

```
.controller("TestCtrl", function($scope, $cordovaInAppBrowser){
    console.log("test ctrl called");
    $scope.submit = function(){
        console.log("submit function  called inside TestCtrl");
        navigator.startApp.start("com.myapp.demo", function (message) {
            /* success */
            alert(" navigator called");
            alert(message);
        },
        function (error) { /* error */
            console.log(error);
            alert(error);
        });
    }
 })
```

Do I need to inject any module from  com.lampa.startapp to my controller? Can anyone please help me to figure this out? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to inject any module.

There are examples here: https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp.

The first thing you must do is to set your parameters and then start the external app:

```
var sApp = startApp.set({
   //write your code here according to the needs
});


startApp.set() return object
```

and then

```
sApp.start(function() { /* success */
  console.log("OK");
}, function(error) { /* fail */
  alert(error);
});
```

My example for open Skype call on button click is:

```
$scope.get_skypeR = function(){
 startApp.set({ /* params */
     "action": "ACTION_VIEW",
     "uri":  "skype:"+skypeID  
 }).start();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this

Comment: @e7lT2P - I am using the same, calling external app with the uri.  However, on Android, the external app opens in my app, not in its own window.  How can I get it to open into its own window?